# Rewriting function to get rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, fetch

I have a function that returns rows from my database, and it works fine but I was told that it was poorly written, and there is a lot of unnecessary code in it.

I'm wondering if there is a simpler, easier way to rewrite this function?

```
function gd($query) {

global $connect;
$fetch = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($fetch);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQLI_NUM)) {

$count --;
$arrayCount = count($myArray);

$tempArrayCount = 0;
while($tempArrayCount < $arrayCount){
$array[$count][$tempArrayCount]= $row[$tempArrayCount];
$tempArrayCount++;
} //end of while($tempArrayCount < $arrayCount)

} //end of while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQLI_NUM)) 

return $array;

} //end of function gd($query)
```

Comment: If your code is functional but you wish to improve it, this is not the place to ask. You better head over to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). On Stack Overflow it's considdered off topic.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite your function in Object oriented style ? Because now this function written in Procedural style.